# Selenium Chrome getting text not work on headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am experiencing a strange behaviour from selenium when running it on headless mode with Chrome webdriver. Up to now, I did not have this problem before to get text in headless mode, it always worked.

The reproduceble example is given bellow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
#options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.zoom.com.br/ar-condicionado/todos")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

stores = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
                                        './/span[@class="storeCount-txt"]')))

print(stores[0].text)
```

When I ran this peace of code the output is:

```
> em 14 lojas
```

However, when I run it on headless mode (remove #s), the output is empty:

```
> ""
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Have you tried `driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)` or whatever your previous resolution is? This will make sure element show up at the same place.

Comment: @Rocky Li didn't work...still empty. Does it work for you on headless mode?

Comment: @RockyLi I tested with Firefox webdriver and it worked. Maybe it is a bug on Chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I was running my webcrawling script deployed in heroku running chrome in headless mode. I solved it by adding the following chrome option to my list of options

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080") #I added this
```

Just as mentioned on the comment in your question, there could be two things that could make some elements not show up

1. The resolution you are on does not display that element(or something like that) which I have solved by adding that option
2. You are searching for the element when it is not yet loaded. I suggest waiting appropriately (which you have done with the stores variable) you could also use this instead

   ```
    try:
       # Wait until 'what you specified' is visible
       WebDriverWait(driver, 60) \
           .until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, './/span[@class="storeCount-txt"]')))
    except Exception as exp:
       print("Exception occured", exp)
       driver.quit()
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path='D:/Java/TestChrome/lib/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.zoom.com.br/ar-condicionado/todos")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

stores = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//span[@class="storeCount-txt"]')))
print("test : " + stores[0].get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Let me know if this work.

Comment: I guess it would be better for OP to know *why* this should work

Comment: Because java scripts call here.so if  you want to get value from it.you should take the attribute value instead of text.I guess you got it what i mean.

Comment: it didn't work for me